# Build testing framework using grunt

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, gruntjs, karma-runner

I am building my angularjs app using grunt.I have created unit test suite for my application using karma.I am trying to setup continuous integration for my application.Before doing a CI in Jenkins,i was trying to build locally using grunt.

1.Copy all the files from app folders into dist (usually done by grunt task 'grunt build')
2.run unit tests on dist folder.
3.Build Artifacts.

I am looking for examples projects and couldn't find any on building test suites along with application using grunt?Any help for references would be great.

Do we have to run test on dist folder or on local app folder when building application using grunt??
Does karma.conf.js file should go into dist folder??

```
 grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:livereload',        
    'karma:continuous',
    'apimocker',    
    'protractor:run'
]);
 ###   Project structure;
```

myProject
    |
    |--app
    |    |--bower_components
    |    |--scripts
    |
    |--dist
    |    |--bower_components
    |    |--scripts
    |
    |--node_modules
    |
    |--test
    |    |--specs
    |
    |--gruntfile.js
    |
    |--karma.conf.js

```
grunt.registerTask('CI', [        
     'clean:dist',
     'useminPrepare',
     'concurrent:dist',
     'autoprefixer',
     'concat',
     'ngmin',
     'copy:dist',
     'cdnify',
     'cssmin',
     'rev',
     'usemin',
     'test',
     'buildArtifacts'
]);

  module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        files: [
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/scripts/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'test/test-main.js', included: true}, 

        ],            
        exclude: [
            'app/scripts/main.js',
            'app/scripts/*min.js',
            'app/scripts/**/*min.js'
        ],
        preprocessors: {},
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',              
            'karma-script-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-requirejs'
        ],
        singleRun: false
    }
);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests need references to all of the app code that we’ll be testing as well as all of the tests that we’ll be writing.

- a testing framework (choose one):

> Jasmine (default), Mocha, QUnit

- any vendor-required code
- our app-specific code
- our test code
- angular-mocks.js library for mocking

  *our app-specific code*  must be your original file output from dist folder (e.g all.js)

For instance, a sample unit test Karma config file might look like the following (comments removed
for simplicity):

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
basePath: '..',
frameworks: ['jasmine'],
files: [
  'lib/angular.js',
  'lib/angular-route.js',
  'test/lib/angular-mocks.js',
  'js/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
],
exclude: [],
port: 8080,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Safari'],
singleRun: false
});
};
```

if you are using a single file for output all js files for example you concatenating all your files into one file e.g all.js then your config must look like this

```
files: [
  'lib/angular.js',
  'lib/angular-route.js',
  'test/lib/angular-mocks.js',
  'js/all.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
],
```

Comment: In my project all the app specific code sits in app folder and dist is like the target folder(compile code) which is created when grunt build is run.This dist(target) folder has all the app specific code.Should karma.conf.js file points to compile code files(dist folder) or source code files(app folder)??